# WebFilter Issue in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway (https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) based on Java Webflux as an API gateway in my environment, and having a confusing time using filters.  The goal is a filter that saves the time when the request hits the server, and logs the duration when it returns a response.  My understanding is a WebFilter is the way to do this, and added one that works sometimes but not others.  In all cases, the pre request part happens, but it frequently doesn't hit the callback.

The WebFilter looks like this:

```
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    var time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return exchange
      .getPrincipal()
      .flatMap(principal -> {
        return chain.filter(exchange);
      })
      .doAfterSuccessOrError((r, t) -> {
        System.out.println("This frequently doesn't happen");
        var duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        recordTime(duration);
    });
  }
```

I setup the routes using RouteLocator:

```
return
  builder.routes()
    .route(r -> r.predicate("/proxypath1")
      .uri("http://localhost:8080"))
    .route(r -> r.predicate("/proxypath2")
      .filters(f -> f.filter(baseFilter))
      .uri("http://localhost:8080"))
```

The weird part about this is the `doAfterSuccessOrError` from the WebFilter will execute as expected for proxypath2, but not for proxypath1.  However, if we add `.filters(f -> f.filter(baseFilter))` to proxypath1, the WebFilter will execute fine.  BaseFilter literally only does this:

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
  return Mono.empty();
}
```

Can someone help me to understand this behavior?  My understanding is the WebFilter should always be executing both the pre and post part, and I don't understand the behavior the GatewayFilter is causing that makes it function in the one case and not the other.